# How can I catch MySQL/MariaDB Exception in my laravel 9 project?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, laravel-9

In my susbcribe form, I have the email field as an PK.
I want to handdle exception error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry".

How can I do it ?
PS : I insert into the DB inside of my Controller

query :

```
if (isset($_POST['nom'], $_POST['prenom'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['cities'])) {
    $nom = request('nom');
    $prenom = request('prenom');
    $email = request('email');
    $ville = request('cities');
    DB::insert('insert into newsletter (nom, prenom, email, ville) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', [$nom, $prenom, $email, $ville]);
}
```

Comment: Show us how you're running the query. Does try/catch not work?

Comment: @ADyson I updated my post check it

Comment: Ok. So, again, does try/catch not work? That's how you catch exceptions in PHP.

Comment: I didn't add a try catch block cause I don't know how to do it in this case of exception @ADyson

Comment: What do you mean? An exception is an exception, they are all caught the same way. It's not clear what you think the problem would be. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: I've tried to just return another view : 
            try {
                DB::insert('insert into newsletter (nom, prenom, email, ville) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', [$nom, $prenom, $email, $ville]);
                return view('newsletter-success', compact('dataInter'));
            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                return view('international', compact('dataInter'));
            }

Comment: But this isn't what I want. once I capture the exception I want to return another thing.

Comment: You can return whatever you want, it's still unclear what exactly the issue is

Comment: @ADyson Ok let's me re explain. I have a PK which is email. Since it's a PK I can't insert the same email twice or whatever. I want to anticipe the error. I imagined a client's email already exists in the DB and he wanted to subscribe again with the same email. He will gets an error. Matter of fact this one "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry". I want to catch this error in order to return my view with an alert saying that's the adress email exists without showing the debug error in the tab of the client

Comment: @ADyson I have managed the catch all of queryExceptions : 
            try {
                DB::insert('insert into newsletter (nom, prenom, email, ville) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', [$nom, $prenom, $email, $ville]);
                return view('newsletter-success', compact('dataInter'));
            }
            catch(QueryException $e) {
                return view ('errors/404');
            }

But I want to catch the exact code error 23000

Comment: Catch the Exception, then inside of the catch block check the message (`$e->getMessage()`) and see if that contains the message you're looking for. Return what you want based on that.  `if(str_contains($e->getMessage(), 'Duplicate entry')) {....`

Comment: Why don't you just run a select to see if it already exists? That's another option

Comment: @ADyson yes but it's another treatment, my app is already big and I don't want to make it even bigger

Comment: Code for that would be no longer than the try/catch code, but ok

Answer (score 0):

```php
// put these at the top of the file with other imports
use Exception; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

try {
    DB::table('newsletter')->insert([
        'nom' => request('nom'),
        'prenom' => request('prenom'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'ville' => request('ville'),
    ]);
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    // do whatever you want when exception happens
    Log::info($exception->getMessage());
}
```